# Code-first Entity Framework, Relating a new table to a view I can't modify

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a read-only view (dbo.HRINFO). I built the below object to represent it. I also have a "User" table that contains a FK to this view, though no official constraint can be defined. I'm trying to establish a navigation property so that whenever I have a "User" object, I can access the "UserInfo/view" data.

```
[Table("dbo.HRINFO")]
public class UserInfo
{
    [Key] // But it's not really a key, there is no key, but it is null or unique
    public string EMAIL_KEY { get; set; }
    ... more properties
}
```

And a table I'm creating that I want to related to the above view:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email_Key { get; set; } // can be a FK to above view
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    ... more properties
}
```

I tried using the fluent API to no avail (the below, as well as many variations):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>().HasKey(t => t.EMAIL_KEY).ToTable("dbo.HRINFO");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(t => t.Id).HasRequired(t => t.UserInfo);
    }
```

I'm at the point that I'm not what I want to do can be done, since I can't add any constraints to the view. Can I instead put a public virtual UserInfo { get { [sql select * from the view where EMAIL_KEY = this.Email_Key] } } on the User object? Or something similar? How?

Comment: I am not able to understand the question . Can you please rephrase it in more details

Comment: *I can't add any constraints to the view* Please explain what you mean by that. Runtime errors? Wrong results? ...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - it's not a view that I have privileges to change. I've got read-only access as it is data owned by another department.

Comment: No, what I mean is that you tell what you tried, but not the result of your efforts. How/why did it fail? I assume that `EMAIL_KEY` being nullable is the show stopper.

Comment: It failed because calling EMAIL_KEY a foreign key tried to establish a constraint during Up(). The database rejected that command because I don't have sufficient rights to add a constraint, so no navigation property was established. It being nullable may have been a showstopper had I made it to the next stage, but it didn't act like that was a problem (yet).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've come up with. I don't like the new context/inner select. I'm sure it will come back to bite me in the future. I'd welcome other ideas.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email_Key { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return new Context().UserInfoes.Single(u => u.EMAIL_KEY == Email_Key);
        }
    }
}
```